# How to cite bibentry in full length in the figure or table caption without using footnote?

Tags: captions, bibentry

I want the full citation shown in the figure or table caption.  I am trying to use **\bibentry** but there are certain errors.  Please help. Here's the MWE.

UPDATE: I have also tried using **\footnotemark** along with **\footnotetext** but that is giving me errors as well.

```
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
year = "1993",
publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

A full in-text cite of \bibentry{goossens93}.

A regular citation of \cite{goossens93}.

Let's check if it works in a table caption.

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering 
\caption{Liquid-solid mass transfer.  Figures redrawn based on the reference~\bibentry{goossens93} used under fair  use, 2014.}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
 Parameter & Symbol & Units & Value & Source & Remarks \tabularnewline  
\hline
Kinematic Viscosity & - & - & - & Melt &\tabularnewline
\hline
Superficial Liquid Velocity & - & - & 0.4-0.5 & - & \tabularnewline
  \hline
  Bed Void Fraction &  & fraction & - & - & \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \end{tabular}}
  \end{table}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\protect\bibentry` should do.

Comment: @egreg That worked super ... Thank you.  Could you put this as an answer so it can be upvoted.  Unfortunately, I didn't see this answer in most of the places I searched ...

Answer (score 3):

The command `\bibentry` is fragile, so it can't be used as is in moving arguments (captions and section titles).

You can use `\protect\bibentry` for the occasional appearance in a caption; if it appears in several of them you can do

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

and then

```
\robustify{\bibentry}
```

after `\usepackage{bibentry}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\robustify{\bibentry}

\nobibliography*

\begin{document}
```

However, I suggest another approach. The bibliographic entry seems just an acknowledgment of source, so you could consider

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Liquid-solid mass transfer}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
 Parameter & Symbol & Units & Value & Source & Remarks \tabularnewline
\hline
Kinematic Viscosity & - & - & - & Melt &\tabularnewline
\hline
Superficial Liquid Velocity & - & - & 0.4-0.5 & - & \tabularnewline
  \hline
  Bed Void Fraction &  & fraction & - & - & \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \end{tabular}}

\begin{quote}\footnotesize
Figures redrawn based on the
reference \bibentry{goossens93} used under fair use, 2014.
\end{quote}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a extremely good solution because now the quoted part does not appear in the list of tables/figures which is what I wanted.

Comment: @ritesh The short caption in the list of tables can be obtained with the optional argument to `\caption`: `\caption[Liquid-solid mass transfer]{Liquid-solid mass transfer. Figure redrawn based on the reference \bibentry{goossens93} used under fair  use, 2014.}` (and `\protect` is not necessary), but this makes the caption too heavy, in my opinion.